# Druapal Ajax Registration form

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-modules

I am using Drupal 7 i am using Ajax Registration module. it is working fine all pages But not working on Home Page.

Here is Link ot website [click Here](http://indivar.info/t2c)

Now here we have login on Top left side when it clicked it redirect to login page but it is supposed to open a popup like all other pages

Anybody have idea about this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using development version of that module Please use recommended  one it will work fine . As it will work fine on my machine too